# Is Memory_used measured in bytes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

> I am running the query `show global status like 'Memory_used'`.

In looking at the [Maria DB documentation for Memory_used](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-status-variables/#memory_used), I began wondering if it is somewhere documented that "all memory variables are measure in X" or something.

**Is *Memory_used* measured in bytes?**  It would be of use to understand where that is mentioned in the documentation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytes.  *But...*  Before 10.2.1, it was only an INT, which is clearly not big enough.  So, don't trust it unless you have a small machine or a new version.

Reference:  https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9518

This seems to be a MariaDB-only setting.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Documentation on Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html) indicates, *"Values for buffer sizes, lengths, and stack sizes are given in bytes unless otherwise specified.*"